# Specification of how MIN/MAX aggregators deal with unbound optional values

Tags: sparql

The aggregators `min` and `max` skip unbound values, at least in Virtuoso and Stardog. Could somebody point me to where this is defined in the [SPARQL 1.1 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/)?

For example given:

```
insert data {
  <http://s1> <http://p1> <http://o1> .
  <http://o1> <http://p2> <http://o2> .
  <http://x> <http://p1> <http://y> .
}
```

the query:

```
select (min(?o2) as ?min) {
  ?s <http://p1> ?o1 .
  optional { ?o1 <http://p2> ?o2 }
}
```

returns `<http://o2>`, ignoring the unbound value for `?o2` for `?s = <http://x>`.

Comment: what do you mean by "skip"? You didn't specify a group via `group by` so it will just return a single value evaluated over all values of `?o2`. Change it to `select ?s (min...` and append `group by ?s` and you might get a different result. Or maybe not, I've no environment here to test it

Comment: Interesting. See the *18.5.1.5 Min* and *15.1 ORDER BY* sections.

Comment: by the way, running the query in Jena returns a single empty value. with `group by ?s` you'll get indeed 2 values, the unbound one and `<http://o2>`

Comment: According to [15.1 order by](https://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/#modOrderBy) unbound values are smaller than other values ("1. (Lowest) no value assigned to the variable"), so smaller than `<http://o2>`. So `?min` should be unbound. Right?

Comment: Which would mean Jena does the right thing, and Stardog and Virtuoso don't.

Comment: in my opinion - and given the fact that the main Jena developer (Andy Seaborne) is one of the editors of the W3C SPARQL 1.1 standard - Apache Jena always follows the SPARQL specs precisely and is the reference implementation (modulo possible bugs) for me when trying out things with SPARQL